# Do Protocol-buffers reuse a string pointer when parsing?

Tags: c++, string, protocol-buffers, heap-memory

I'm working with Protocol Buffers, and trying to minimize calls to the heap.

In the example, `PhoneNumber` has a required member called number which is a string.

```
  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }
```

When I generate the code I get this pointer member in `Person_PhoneNumber`:

`::std::string* number_;`

So I'm wondering if this string is going to be reused when I call `parseFrom` on an already existing `Person_PhoneNumber`

I had a look at the generated code, but it's hard to decode, especially considering all the calls to `GetEmptyStringAlreadyInited` and the `SharedCtor`

Comment: Try it and see? Store the value of the pointer then parse another message, and see if the pointers are equal?

Comment: I've tried. They point to the same address and the `capacity` stayed the same which is a good sign. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No problem. Of course this does mean that if you want to retain the string from a message, you need to copy the string before reusing that message object. (But you probably know this already.)

Comment: I often use test and see, if it succeeds I go a step further and see why, because its no prof that it will be the same next time, or with next patch or another variable order etc. If you are sending the message as const it better be the same when it comes back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you reuse the same message object for multiple parses, all sub-objects will be reused as well. In fact, the `Clear()` method never deletes anything, but just marks everything for reuse. The only way to cause any memory to be freed is to actually destroy the top-level object.

This is a key performance feature, but it can sometimes lead to undesirable memory usage if you parse messages with many different "shapes", since the total memory footprint will end up being the union of all those "shapes". You can use the `SpaceUsed()` method to determine how much memory is currently being used by a message and free objects that get too big.

Comment: Is SpaceUsed() a reliable function to get a deserialized message size?

Comment: @MarkoBencik Depends on what you mean. SpaceUsed() returns the amount of memory currently used by the protobuf object. If you reuse the same object for multiple messages, it may hold on to sub-objects it allocated in the past in the hopes of reusing them later, even if the current message doesn't have those sub-objects. So SpaceUsed() is not really a way to measure the size of a particular message; it's a way to measure current memory usage of a protobuf object.

Comment: SO if I understand you correctly it gives the size of the current deserialized allocation. That is excellent what I was hoping for. I will need to test how fast it is, but this helps.